# Why in python it generate modulenotfinderror even after installation of module and add the path in environment variable

Tags: visual-studio, module, nlp, nltk, python-3.11

In my python program it generate modulenotfounderror.

I want a valid solution for this kind of error.this error is arise a lot of problem to run the python program. I have added the path of python and sites packages and vs code and installed all modules .after all of these thing my project generated modulenotfounderror what should i do ?
Please help me to out of this problem .